# What's the basic pattern for testing ajax requests with web-component-tester w/o sinon server?

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer, web-component-tester

How do I setup the following element/test with web-component-tester and polymer such that (1) the XHR request completes, (2) *then* the assert runs, causing (3) the test to pass?

/my-element.html

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
  <iron-request id="req"><iron-request>
  </template>

  <script>
    (function() {
      'use strict';

      Polymer({
        is: 'my-element',
        properties: {
          newVal: Object
        },
        fetchedStuff: function(ironRequest) {
          this.set('newVal', ironRequest.response);
          console.log('This gets logged after tests run.'); // <--- this is firing too late!
        },
        ready: function() {
          this.$.req.resolveCompletes = this.fetchedStuff;
          this.$.req.send({url: '/my.json'});
        }
      });
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

/my-element-test.html

```
<test-fixture id="basic">
  <template>
     <my-element></my-element>
  </template>
</test-fixture>

<script>
  suite('my-element tests', function() {
    test('Item lengths should be equalled', function(done) {
      element = fixture('basic');
      flush(function() {
        assert.equal(element.newVal, {"name": "Polymer"});
        done();
      });
    })
  });
</script>
```

**Background**:

We'd like to test ajax calls without using the Sinon server provided in web-component-tester (that is, we'd like to make *real* xhr calls. We'd like to do this because the xhr requests should return content from files that are automatically generated from a different system.

FWIW, I've tried putting callbacks and promises in various places, including using an iron-ajax element, and I can't seem to find an ideal way to solve this. The only solution I've found so far, is to create an event called "executeTests," which seems jenky.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34214429/testing-polymer-1-0-components-with-iron-ajax-using-wct